# What does the title "Return of the Jedi" refer to?

Tags: star-wars, return-of-the-jedi, title-explanation

Which entity does the "Jedi" in the title "Return of the Jedi" refer to? Does it refer to the general return of the Jedi Knights to the galaxy via Luke, or does it specifically refer to the redemption of Darth Vader and the return of the Jedi Anakin Skywalker, Chosen One of the prophesy?